# Find the unique polynomial $P\in P_3$such that, >$P^{"} -2P^{'}+P=x^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $P_3$ denote the (real) vector space of all polynomials (in one variable),
>   with real coefficients and of degree less than, or equal to, 3, equipped with
>   the standard basis. Find the unique polynomial $P\in P_3$such that,
>   $P^{"} -2P^{'}+P=x^{3}$

I am openly saying I don't know what I want to find.

Can anyone please help me .. If this question is already in stackexchange sorry ..Please guide me to find the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

Then differentiate to get expressions for $P'$ and $P''$

Put the three expressions you have together to create one expression for $P''-2P'+P$

To have this equal to $x^3$ you must now look at the coefficient of $x^3$ and make it equal to $1$. The coefficients of $x^2$ and $x$ must be equal to $0$. Finally the constant term must be $0$.

This process will give you a set of equations in $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. Solve them and you have your polynomial.

Comment: Thank you so much sir .I got it @tomi